# Why $(this) is referring to a wrapped set instead of an individual element?

Tags: jquery

In this function,

```
template.find('.userPhoto img').error(function () { 
    $(this)[0].src = '/images/default.png'; 
}).attr('src', image);
```

I was expecting **$(this)** to refer to an individual element, but it's not; instead, it's referring to a wrapped set... can you spot why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because that's what $(...) means.

Comment: FWIW, `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: How do you know it's a set? THe `[0]` addresses the DOM element of the jQuery object, not the first element

Comment: So tempting to answer "Yes, cause I've googled it..."

Comment: @Pekka: Can you tell me which part of jquery makes sure that when you get [0] you'll actually get DOM element?

Comment: @Martin I don't know the exact line number in the code that does it, but it is the convention that the original DOM node is stored in `.0` (or `[0]`). It doesn't look like a great choice, as it can confuse people (as this question shows) but maybe they had a reason for it

Comment: @Martin. that's just how it works.  Unless for some reason you generated an empty set.

Comment: @Pekka: [got it](https://gist.github.com/75d4dacefc154f4e00b6). Am I correct?

Comment: @Pekka there's no such convention - a jQuery object when accessed like an array, gives you all of the elements matching the selector.  If the object passed to the `$()` constructor was a DOM element then what you get is a jQuery object with _one_ element in it.

Comment: @Alnitak that's a different issue, isn't it? In the code above, `$(this)` will always return *one* jQuery object. That object's member `[0]` is the actual, native DOM element. The code uses `[0].src` to directly write into the `src` property for some reason (instead of using `attr()` as they should).

Comment: @Pekka sure, but it's not a "convention" - there's nothing special about element 0.  It's just how jQuery works!

Comment: @Pekka oh, and using `element.src` is actually better than using `$(element).attr(src, ...)`.

Comment: @ALnitak in this context, you're right of course, disregard what I said. But if you are explicitly working with a jQuery object, you generally want to use its setters and getters to comb over browser incompatibilities

Comment: @Pekka right, I wouldn't bother to unwrap a jQuery object if I was going to re-use it (or chain another function call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `$(this)` is referring to a wrapped set instead of an individual element?

Because someone didn't know any better.

In this context if you want the original DOM element, just use `this`

On the other hand, if you wish to call jQuery methods on that element, use `$(this)`.

Since all you're doing is setting a property of a DOM element, you should use the former:

```
template.find('.userPhoto img').error(function () { 
    this.src = '/images/default.png'; 
}).attr('src', image);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because so you can apply a method to a selection and have an unified api

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $(this).each(...).click(...);
});
$("a").click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how jQuery works, it's the expected behavior.

`$()` turns DOM element(s) into a jQuery object (which pretends to be an array), which is a set of DOM element(s).

In your answer you don't need to use `$()`.

Since, `this` is the element you want, you can just do:

```
template.find('.userPhoto img').error(function () { 
    this.src = '/images/default.png'; 
}).attr('src', image);
```

Or you can do this:

```
template.find('.userPhoto img').error(function () { 
    $(this).attr('src', '/images/default.png';);
}).attr('src', image);
```

`$(this).attr('src'` will change the attribute of all elements (in your case, one) in the set.